# Scroll down page in 100 pixels with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to make a page scroll down 100px with setTimeout ( 9 sc )

**Scroll to bottom with setTimeout**

```
window.onload = toBottom;

function toBottom() {
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
window.onload = setTimeout(toBottom, 9000);
```

**Scroll down page with pixel**

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 100
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a huge problem with your code other than not putting it inside a setTimeout.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 100
  });
},9000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:1100px;width:1px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll down to the bottom then instead of using **setTimeout** use **setInterval** like below :

```
setInterval(function(){$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 100
});},9000);
```

In case you want to stop auto scrolling, once bottom is reached then use below :

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 100
});},9000);

$(window).scroll(function(){
     var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    var htWindow = $("html body").prop('scrollHeight')-$(window).height() ;   
    if(height  >= htWindow) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
});
```

Comment: :/ Not work with jquery.min.slim.js , look my example code

Comment: That's because **animate** function is not defined in that library. Include below line in your head tab : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`